# Empty variable when using `status.hostIP` as reference field for my env variable in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, datadog

I'm deploying a kubernetes pod using helm v3, my kubectl client and server are above 1.7 so it should support reference fields. However when i deploy, the value is just empty.

using

```
environment:
  - name: DD_AGENT_HOST
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

Where the DD_AGENT_HOST is my env variable that should be given the host ip.

Any idea on why this might be happening?

Comment: Fixed, apparently helm doesn't copy it correctly

Comment: Can you post it as an answer, to be more visible for community ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to add it this to the container specification directly, not passing from an env and using `include` from helm as that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to helm app deployment template(IF you use one). For instance, if you have *deployment.yaml* with

```
      env:
      {{- range .Values.env }}
        - name: {{ .name }}
          value: {{ .value | quote }}
      {{- end }}
```

And one of `env` values is `valueFrom`, you have to add explicitly (unless there is a nicer way of doing it):

```
        - name: DD_AGENT_HOST
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

Otherwise copy of the `range` above will not use `valueFrom`and as a result `DD_AGENT_HOST` will be empty